Select lowest time depending price
I am trying to make a query that determines the most favorable, time-dependent prices for a certain period, but also does not exclude objects for which no prices are available for this period.
Since the price periods can be completely flexible, it is not possible to work with larger and smaller queries.
I therefore thought that the smallest difference between start and end should be determined and the smallest price taken (if there are several hits).
Price table



id
oid
start
end
price




1
1000
2024-04-13
2025-04-13
120


2
1001
2024-04-13
2025-04-13
200


3
1002
2024-05-04
2024-08-13
1225


4
1002
2024-08-14
2024-10-14
1400


5
1002
2024-10-15
2024-12-31
200


6
1006
2024-01-01
2024-03-01
5250


61684
115
2025-12-27
2026-01-03
575


61683
115
2025-12-20
2025-12-26
510


61682
115
2025-11-01
2025-12-19
500


61681
115
2025-10-11
2025-10-31
570


61680
115
2025-09-13
2025-10-10
515


61679
115
2025-08-30
2025-09-12
615


61678
115
2025-07-12
2025-08-29
800


61677
115
2025-07-05
2025-07-11
615


61676
115
2025-06-07
2025-07-04
515


61675
115
2025-04-26
2025-06-06
480


61674
115
2025-04-12
2025-04-25
570


61673
115
2025-03-29
2025-04-11
480


61672
115
2025-01-04
2025-03-28
475


61671
115
2024-12-28
2025-01-03
550


61670
115
2024-12-21
2024-12-27
470


61669
115
2024-11-02
2024-12-20
450


61668
115
2024-10-19
2024-11-01
525


61667
115
2024-09-07
2024-10-18
470


61666
115
2024-08-24
2024-09-06
540


61665
115
2024-07-06
2024-08-23
725


61664
115
2024-06-22
2024-07-05
560


61663
115
2024-05-18
2024-06-21
472


61662
115
2024-04-06
2024-05-17
457



Object table



id
title
published




115
object_115
1


1000
object_0
1


1001
object_1
1


1002
object_2
1


1006
object_6
1



So far I have had this query:
SELECT p.id AS pid
FROM
    prices AS p
    LEFT JOIN objects o ON o.id = p.oid
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT oid, MIN(
                ABS(
                    DATEDIFF(start, '2024-05-10') + DATEDIFF(end, '2024-05-17')
                )
            ) AS diff
        FROM prices
            LEFT JOIN objects o ON o.id = oid
        WHERE
            o.published = 1
        GROUP BY
            oid
    ) p2 ON p.oid = p2.oid
    AND (
        ABS(
            DATEDIFF(p.start, '2024-05-10') + DATEDIFF(p.end, '2024-05-17')
        )
    ) = p2.diff
WHERE
    o.published = 1

The problem with this query is that it does not return the cheapest price if there is a price with an end date that has a higher negative amount.
So I did that:
SELECT p.id AS pid
FROM
    prices AS p
    LEFT JOIN objects o ON o.id = p.oid
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT oid, MIN(
                ABS(
                    DATEDIFF(start, '2024-05-10') + DATEDIFF(end, '2024-05-17')
                )
            ) AS diff
        FROM prices
            LEFT JOIN objects o ON o.id = oid
        WHERE
            o.published = 1
            AND DATEDIFF(end, '2024-06-15') >= 0 /* NEW */
        GROUP BY
            oid
    ) p2 ON p.oid = p2.oid
    AND (
        ABS(
            DATEDIFF(p.start, '2024-05-10') + DATEDIFF(p.end, '2024-05-17')
        )
    ) = p2.diff
WHERE
    o.published = 1

This (I believe) always produces the lowest prices, BUT it ignores properties that only have prices in the past. However, these should be taken into account.
Object 115 should output 457,- as cheapest price, but it outputs 472,-
New fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/547rVXPa
When adding the new LIne 15 object_6 is missing.

Would you be so kind to provide also the desired output

which version of MySql or Mariadb are you using

@nbk it can be different versions on common hosting

Object 115 is not in the first fiddle you provided. Please provide an updated fiddle.

I provided first fiddle, but I am not going to update it.....

@Luuk sorry ;). I updated it.

Object 115 does output 457,- as cheapest price. Please clarify the expected output.

@BartMcEndree Yes, it does. It seems the question is ill-defined.

Object_6 is missing because it has an end date of   2024-03-01 and DATEDIFF(end, '2024-05-17')  = -77.. see fiddle with unfiltered intermediate values https://dbfiddle.uk/mQOwdM5a

Sounds like a "groupwise-max" pattern.  (Or -min)

No solution so far

@maidan: What did you do with the comments give here? like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78461167/select-lowest-time-depending-price?noredirect=1#comment138324429_78461167;  and the comments after that?   Please share feedback on the comments and improve your question based on the feedback given. (see: Respond to feedback after posting)
